# Java generics: why does this nested template fail?

Tags: java, nested-generics

I have a situation that could be summarized as follows:

```
interface Hello<T> {
};

interface World<T, U> {
    void apply(Hello<T> t, Hello<U> u);
}
```

Now let's say I'd like to call `World.apply` without caring about the nested types, so I tried the following:

```
Hello<?> hello = ...;
World<?, ?> world = ...;
world.apply(hello, hello);
```

But I get this obscure message:

```
java: incompatible types: Hello<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to Hello<capture#2 of ?>
```

What's wrong here? Is there a way to accomplish that, besides resorting to raw types?

Casting `world` to `World<Object, Object>` is a way, but is there anything better?

Comment: _"this nested template"_ Java doesn't have templates; be careful when trying to apply template semantics from another language (C++?) in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` means that it's unclear what a datatype is it actually. Unknown and unknown are incompatible to each other, because in fact it could be for instance `Integer` and `String`:

```
Hello<?> hello = new HelloImpl<Integer>();
World<?, ?> world = new WorldImpl<String,String>();
```

Types are unknown in the compilation time.